# does the processor switch data from 'L1 code' to 'L1 data' cache?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86-64, self-modifying

I would like to know, how does the microprocessor (lets say on SandyBridge architecture in long mode) switches data from 'L1 code' to 'L1 data' cache and vice versa ? 
Lets say a page was used for data storage, so it is cached in L1 cache. Then , during the execution of the OS, the instruction pointer jumps (issuing a JMP instruction) to the memory location that is currently cached in L1 data cache. Does the processor migrates data from L1 data to L1 code cache? Same question for when the data management instruction is issued on an address that is stored in L1 code cache (i.e. meaning that the address became good for data storage, not code execution)
How does the processor handles these issues?

I am asking this because I am studying about self modifying code, if you have any additional info where I could read details about code cache, please post the link/reference.

Comment: In general (not referring to any specific processor architecture) this is a problem.  In some architectures, unless you do some specific operation to cause the change to be reflected in the instruction cache, it is highly likely to not be "seen" by instruction fetch.  Others are a little friendlier (at some cost in additional circuitry and possibly some performance penalties).  In some cases you need to execute a branch before the change will be recognized.

Comment: In general they would be separate caches.  the data operation and instruction fetch being separate.  If the address you are modifying using data operations is in the L1 cache then when you jump to it the cached version is used not your modified one.  Even worse if some of the code you execute is the stale code and some is newly modified, unpredictable results.  If you want to do this you need to invalidate the instruction cache lines, dont worry about the data cache.  If the cache is shared I and D then you are good BTW.

Answer (score 3):

See the latest [intel programmer's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-2a-2b-3a-3b-manual.html), vol 3, system programming, specifically these sections:

- 8.1.3 Handling Self- and Cross-Modifying Code
- 11.6 SELF-MODIFYING CODE

I don't think you want to know and become reliant on the behavior of specific CPU models, because it will make your code unstable on different or newer CPUs. Just follow the official guidelines on how to design and execute self and cross-modifying code.

And you don't want to do a lot of code modification at run time because of the associated performance penalties due to cache invalidation.

Comment: Get a [pdf version](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-2a-2b-3a-3b-manual.pdf) if it doesn't show up in the browser. It says many things. To execute the new code you'll need to either jump to it directly or transfer control to it via some intermediate code or to execute a serializing instruction (e.g. CPUID), then the new code can be run. In multiprocessor systems it's done a bit differently.

Comment: Still, "download a 4000 page PDF" isn't a very good answer, and will be useless once Intel breaks the link.

Comment: @Gabe: they break their links all the time. Shorter versions are currently available [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: Anyway, if the processor migrates data from the L1D to L1C or writeback to L2, and the refetches L1C from L2 is not clearly stated in the programmers manual. I suspect it may be different for different processor models. @Nulik: In what way would that be relevant to you?

Comment: @Gabe  No, this doesn't answer the question because the manuals focus on 32 bit architecture and in long mode we don't rely on CS anymore. So this is the answer (the best approximation) I have found with help of comp.lang.asm.x86: All memory writes go through 'L1 data' cache because of physical organization of the processor. I think there is no direct transistor communication to 'L1 code' so the processor can't update it directly, the only way it can update 'L1 code' is to read it from L2. This explains the performance hit for using self modifying code.

Comment: @drhirsch The reasons I am asking is that I thought that if I would save registers in the code itself (instead of pushing them on the stack), I would not evict the cache lines from 'L1 data', but apparently it is not the case.

Comment: @Nulik: saving registers in the code itself...  unlikey to be a very good idea, because of the costs involved.